# .net xmlserializer error

Tags: .net, xml-serialization

The error is when the class gets serialized, I don't get a run time error or anything (unless I try to deserialize). When the XmlSerializer serializes my class, some times it adds some text at then end of the XML. This happens often at the very end:

```
</RootNode>ootNode>
```

Some times it's not at the end but in the middle, something like

```
<Node Name="MyNode">
    Name="MyNode">
    <Attribute1>Attr</Attribute1>
```

I have no idea what could be causing this, but maybe it has happened to some of you too. Let me know if you guys found a solution to this problem.

Here's my code:

```
        using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(
            File.Open(fileName, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.ReadWrite)))
        {
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyClass));

            serializer.Serialize(writer, this);
        }
```

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe you could post your code? it's likely not the XmlSerializer, but perhaps if you're reading from or writing to a file, you're picking up some stale data there. It's hard to tell without seeing some code.

Comment: I recall seeing this before, but can really not remember where or what I did to work around it... Sorry :(

Comment: I'll post my code, but it's very simple. One sec.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using the wrong `FileMode`. `OpenOrCreate` will not truncate the contents of the file if it already exists, thereby causing your new data to be overlaid on top of the old data. `FileMode.Create` will do what you want.